# csh different from bash when expend ＊NAME＊ patten to file name list

Tags: shell

I am a newbie for shell script.

I noticed that for command like:

```
tar cf test.tar *TEST* *TEST2*
```

sh and bash will expand *TEST* to a list of file names, while csh will not. 
I want the shell not to expend, how can I do this?

Use ' or " will lead to other problems. If there is files match pattern *TEST*, but no files match *TEST2*,
then the tar will fail.

[EDIT]I think this is an expend difference between bash and csh.
When no pattern found for *TEST*, csh will expend to "", while bash will expend to '*TEST*' (add quote char).

Comment: Use quotes: `'*TEST*' '*TEST2*'`, `"*TEST*" "*TEST2*"`, or use backslash: `\\*TEST\\* \\*TEST2\\*`.

Comment: This does not work. 
tar: *TEST*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> If the nullglob option is set, and no 
>   matches  are  found,  the  word  is
>   removed.

For example:

```
betelgeuse:TEST james$ touch TEST1 TEST3
betelgeuse:TEST james$ ls *TEST* *TEST2*
ls: *TEST2*: No such file or directory
TEST1   TEST3
betelgeuse:TEST james$ shopt -s nullglob
betelgeuse:TEST james$ ls *TEST* *TEST2*
TEST1   TEST3
```

This is approximately equivalent to the `csh` behaviour:

```
[betelgeuse:/tmp/TEST] james% ls *TEST* *TEST2*
TEST1   TEST3
```

The difference is that `csh` will return an error if *all* of the filename patterns on a line fail to match anything:

```
[betelgeuse:/tmp/TEST] james% ls *TEST4* *TEST2*
ls: No match.
```

while `bash` will just return an list of tokens to the command, leading to oddities such as this:

```
betelgeuse:TEST james$ ls *TEST4* *TEST2*
TEST1   TEST3
```

`*TEST4*` and `*TEST2*` both return nothing; so the `ls` command believes it has been called  with no arguments and just gives a listing of the directory. In your example, tar would (rightly) complain that it's being given no files to work on.

Comment: Cool! is there a standard way both for all posix standard platform for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the default `bash` behaviour (if the pattern matches nothing, leave the pattern unchanged) is the correct POSIX behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
shopt -s nullglob
tar cf test.tar *TEST* 2>/dev/null
```

newer version of Solaris comes with bash already. So you can try using bash. If your version of Solaris doesn't have bash, I guess you just have to do it the "longer" way.

```
for file in *TEST*
do 
   tar uf test.tar "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your arguments in single quotes or escape them:

```
 tar cf test.tar '*TEST*' '*TEST2*'
```

or

```
 tar cf test.tar \*TEST\* \*TEST2\*
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the string in single quotes:

```
tar cf test.tar '*TEST2*'
```

Comment: use '' will lead to other problem for tar (if *TEST2* can not find a match). but without ', csh works well.

Comment: Do you have asterixes in your filenames, or what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Put * into single quotes, i.e. `'*'`

Answer (score 0):

As answered by others, the immediate solution is to put * inside single-quoted string or to escape it with a backslash.

Anyway, using a star character in a filename, though not forbidden, is a very bad idea.

Comment: I actually want a patten match. Not a star character in a filename.